# Is there a function to remove alphanumeric words given a sentence using python

Tags: python-3.x, text, nlp

Given a sentence "hi I stay at 4th cross street and my ssn number is 56tyuh". I want to remove words such as alphanumeric ( 4th and 56tyuh ). Does isalpha() is used only to check if there are alphanumerics in sentences? If not how do I use it to remove alphanumerics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use regex for this. Regex can be confusing but in this case, it's quite straight forward.

```
import re

s = 'hi I stay at 4th cross street and my ssn number is 56tyuh'
r = r'\S*\d+\S*'
cut_string = re.sub(r, '', s)
```

Let's break this down:
`r` is a regex variable, which detects character sequences of 0-n leading non-whitespace characters, followed by 1-n numeric charcters and again 0-n trailing non-whitespace characters.

`re.sub` replaces the matches of our regex with the second parameter, in our case an empty string. Thus it removes all matches of our regex from the string.

Edit:

This will also remove numbers. If you only want to remove alphanumeric words, make the follwing change:

```
r = r'([a-zA-Z]*\d+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\d+[a-zA-Z]*)'
```

Note the `|` in the center of the variable. This means *either* match the first part within the parentheses or the second. The first would match `4th` but not `ep95`, the opposite is true for the second.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Any idea on why the numbers are also removed along with alphanumerics?

Comment: I thought you wanted to also remove numbers. Please see my edit.